# Adapt code to my mySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql, cron, geocoding

I have a table, "jos_ezrealty" that has address, city, state fields and declat & declong for latitude and longitude. I need to adapt the code below (provided by google - http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlgeocode.html) to work with my table. All of my address fields are filled, and half of my lat & long fields are filled. I want to use the code below to fill in the missing lat & long information (don't worry about geocoding request limits, as I only have 300 properties and this code only fills in the missing ones)

Thanks -

```
    <?php
require("phpsqlgeocode_dbinfo.php");

define("MAPS_HOST", "maps.google.com");
define("KEY", "abcdefg");

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die("Not connected : " . mysql_error());
}

// Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die("Can\'t use db : " . mysql_error());
}

// Select all the rows in the markers table
$query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
}

// Initialize delay in geocode speed
$delay = 0;
$base_url = "http://" . MAPS_HOST . "/maps/geo?output=xml" . "&key=" . KEY;

// Iterate through the rows, geocoding each address
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $geocode_pending = true;

  while ($geocode_pending) {
    $address = $row["address"];
    $id = $row["id"];
    $request_url = $base_url . "&q=" . urlencode($address);
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url) or die("url not loading");

    $status = $xml->Response->Status->code;
    if (strcmp($status, "200") == 0) {
      // Successful geocode
      $geocode_pending = false;
      $coordinates = $xml->Response->Placemark->Point->coordinates;
      $coordinatesSplit = split(",", $coordinates);
      // Format: Longitude, Latitude, Altitude
      $lat = $coordinatesSplit[1];
      $lng = $coordinatesSplit[0];

      $query = sprintf("UPDATE markers " .
             " SET lat = '%s', lng = '%s' " .
             " WHERE id = '%s' LIMIT 1;",
             mysql_real_escape_string($lat),
             mysql_real_escape_string($lng),
             mysql_real_escape_string($id));
      $update_result = mysql_query($query);
      if (!$update_result) {
        die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
      }
    } else if (strcmp($status, "620") == 0) {
      // sent geocodes too fast
      $delay += 100000;
    } else {
      // failure to geocode
      $geocode_pending = false;
      echo "Address " . $address . " failed to geocoded. ";
      echo "Received status " . $status . "
\n";
    }
    usleep($delay);
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Could someone please edit this entry to make fix the code?

Comment: The code has been indentinated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly you need to adapt your database schema into the code  example provided by google.

If that is the case then if your database follows the google example i.e.

```
CREATE TABLE `markers` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`name` VARCHAR( 60 ) NOT NULL ,
`address` VARCHAR( 80 ) NOT NULL ,
`lat` FLOAT( 10, 6 ) NOT NULL ,
`lng` FLOAT( 10, 6 ) NOT NULL ,
`type` VARCHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

You only have to rename your table to `markers` or change and change the `$database` value at the `phpsqlgeocode_dbinfo.php` or change the queries to select your table.

Otherwise please specify your problem.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're asking for MyISAM in your CREATE statement?  There's nothing in the table that would need MyISAM (no FULLTEXT indexes, etc), so InnoDB should be used instead.

Comment: Indeed. I just copy/pasted the table structure from the google examples.